# Need to run npm install with sudo, else I get Errno -5

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

I `git clone` a Node app.

Then I try to install all the dependencies with `npm install`.
I get the following error.

```
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, read

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/foobar/.npm/_logs/2020-02-22T12_14_17_084Z-debug.log
```

The last lines of the log file look like this:

```
...
...
3830 silly saveTree └── typescript@3.8.2
3831 verbose stack Error: EIO: i/o error, read
3832 verbose cwd /home/foobar/myapp
3833 verbose Linux 5.4.18-1-MANJARO
3834 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
3835 verbose node v13.7.0
3836 verbose npm  v6.13.6
3837 error code EIO
3838 error syscall read
3839 error errno -5
3840 error EIO: i/o error, read
3841 verbose exit [ -5, true ]
```

When I prepend the command with `sudo` it installs.

How can I fix this error so I don't need to run `npm install` with `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by deleting my ~/.npm and other node related directories in $HOME.